# How do I convert HTML NSData to an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdata

I'm using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` to create two NSData instances and I want to compare these instances to gauge how different they are. Since they're both from the same website, using a string to find what is different will help me highlight the actual element(s) that has (have) changed. Is it possible to change this data to a string to find the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `initWithData:encoding:` method of NSString to create string with your data.

Exmp: `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use NSString 
[stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL%3aencoding%3aerror%3a)

Comment: @caterpape: Whatever encoding the text is in to begin with. But I'd probably recommend non-lossy ASCII since you are just comparing two strings anyway.

Comment: As @william-totland mentioned start with [NSASCIIStringEncoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSASCIIStringEncoding) and consider revising if the output does not satisfy you (you work with non-ascii data, e.g. Russian, Chinese, etc).