# Parse - How to save a html file in iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiwebview

I'm using Parse for my iOS app and I'm trying to locally save my HTML file from Parse core data to my device's local storage. I'm doing this so the user can still access the data even when they're offline. I've read about local datastore and cache policy and have tried both. With local datastore, it doesn't let me load the HTML to my UIWebView but it loads everything else (probably due to the HTML needing internet to access it). Cache policy actually works but only accesses the more recent items (just as a cache should work).

I am asking on here to see what I can do to locally save these HTML files from Parse so a user can access them even when the internet is gone.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: [Ray Wenderlich: storing app data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data). Will you also need to store any linked images, stylesheets and/or scripts with your HTML from Parse?

Comment: Oh wow! thanks I totally forgot to look on that site. I'll try it out. I ultimately will be trying to store linked html and linked images. Will that work with the NSCoding tutorial pulling from Parse? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PFFile`'s method `getData` to get `NSData` and save it to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
let data = file.getData()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: file.name)
```

...and when you need to read it:

```
let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey(file.name)
```

This can help you display the page in WebView: [How do I convert HTML NSData to an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719890/how-do-i-convert-html-nsdata-to-an-nsstring)

**Update**: `UIWebView` has method to show `NSData`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:

Comment: I am not too familiar with using `NSUserDefaults` so I'm wondering how much I could potentially store from this. I could have up to a 100 files to store in the future so would this practical? Thanks

Comment: @Ryan NSUserDefaults values are stored in .plist file, is has no limits except available space on the device.

Comment: Thanks! This helped out alot